# Вопрос о пакинге виджетов в GTK

Tags: gtk

Делаю динамическое приложение на GTK, и так получается, что в первое время у меня есть всего один виджет, который надо поместить на экран, что я и делаю:

```
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), widget);
```

Но дальше возможно создание ещё одного виджета, который также надо поместить на экран. В GTK для этого нужно создать бокс, запаковать в него виджет и добавить бокс на экран:

```
GtkWidget *box = gtk_vbox_new(0, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), widget, 0, 0, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), widget2, 0, 0, 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);
```

Но на этот момент у меня нету доступа к widget, только widget2, да и его нужно поместить на экран ещё в самом начале, следовательно было бы логично сделать бокс в начале и поместить туда первый widget. А потом, когда потребуется, создать второй виджет и запаковать его во всё тот же бокс.

```
GtkWidget *box = gtk_vbox_new(0, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), widget, 0, 0, 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);
...
...
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), widget2, 0, 0, 0);
```

Теперь проблема: Бокс может быть или только вертикальным или только горизонтальным, одно из двух, а как именно мне нужно будет поместить на экран widget2 я знать на могу.
В примере выше у меня получатся два виджета расположенные вертикально. Но если нужно будет поместить их горизонтально? Никак. А если нужно будет поместить два виджета вертикально, и под ними третий? Тоже никак.

Единственное решение, которое я вижу, это паковать всё в конце, когда известны все виджеты, но оно мне не подходит. У меня, можно сказать, если один центральный объект, на который я хочу постепенно лепить другие объекты с каких угодно сторон. В GTK так можно?

Comment: В GTK можно реализовать очень много. Опишите более конкретно что хотите реализовать.

Answer (score -1):

На заметку: в исходниках пакета `gtk+3.0` есть директория `tests`, в которой можно найти файл `testtoolbar.c` с возможностью менять ориентацию панели инструментов.